# getSupportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(tag,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) pop out all fragments

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, back

How to return to specific `fragment` in android?

I have used `getSupportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(tag,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)`

to pop upto particular fragment. But it pop out all fragments.

Comment: well that's exactly how stack works, `1->2->3->4` and if you want to access **3** now you have to pop **4**

Comment: please provide code and exact scenario of what you want to do.

Comment: @AbdulKawee from activity, go to 1 ->2 ->3. From 3, I need to go to 1 and don't show 2 in any further back navigation.

Comment: @SharmaGN please check the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to directly jump to your desired fragment you can do this in this way

```
 Fragment oneFragment= fragmentManager
            .findFragmentByTag("tagOfYourFragmentHere");
 if (oneFragment!= null){

  fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameContainer, OneFragment.createNewInstance(YourActivity.this),
                    "One Fragment").commit();    // replace with your data
  }
```

Hope this solves your problem.